# Make html text not transform into html

Tags: html, tags, plaintext

So I have made a guestbook (http://guestbook.ssdfkx.ch) which has a bug I can't get rid of myself. When you submit an entry and write in HTML text, it is converted into HTML and not plain text. This leads to the problem that one person can mess up the whole website in seconds.

I have tried it with the `<plaintext>` tag. But if I do so, even when I close the tag again, everything from the tag down turns into plain text.

Help is appreciated. The following is my code:

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_object($ergebnis)) {
        $message = $row->message;
        $name = $row->name;
        $date = $row->date;
        $id = $row->id;
        $datetime = new DateTime($date);
        $formatteddate = $datetime->format('d.m.Y');
        $formattedmessage = nl2br($message);
        if ($_SESSION['logged_in'] == true) {
            $entryfeld =    '<article>
                                <div>
                                    <main>
                                        <div class="innerdiv">
                                            <p>'.$formattedmessage.'</p>
                                        </div>
                                    </main>
                                        <div class="innerleft">
                                            <form method="POST">
                                            <input name="id" type="hidden" value="'. $id . '"/>
                                            <input name="löschen" class="deletebutton" id="deletebutton" value="Löschen" type="submit">    </form>
                                            <br/>
                                            <p      id="innerleftp">'.$name.'</p>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="innerrightdel">
                                            <p>'.$formatteddate.'</p>
                                        </div>
                                </div>
                            </article>';
```

EDIT: Well, the variable `$formattedmessage` is what the user enters. If the user enters HTML it actually converts it which should not be happening. I tried using the `<plaintext>` tag before and after the variable. It somehow changed everything after the variable into plain text and not only the user input.

Comment: We need to see some code so we can help you :)

Comment: @Tom Fuller added;)

Comment: i don't get what you want? want to make $formattedmessage non html plain text??

Comment: the $formattedmessage is an input from the user saved in a database. If the user types in html like <input type="button"> on th website there will be a buttton instead of plain text. It should not transform into html buttons and co but stay html plain text

Comment: how about use strip_tags() function

Comment: @reza that would help, but it just deletes the whole html. I want that it prints the html as normal text in a paragraph

Comment: you can choose which tag element to remove in this function

Comment: @reza yes but I don't know which html tags the user wants to enter. Like I said, it's a user input and i have no hand over it except in this script